# CKEDITOR 4 in Bootsrap Model save previously written text on undo

Tags: model, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor in Bootsrap Model PopUp and when I open Popup it shows me the text I wrote previously. Using this `CKEDITOR.instances.noteBody.setData("")` I can reset its text but what I want to completely clear text history. As If I reset using this line `CKEDITOR.instances.noteBody.setData("");` It will show me proevious text if I click undo. What I want is make CKEDITOR forget what was written before...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my question, use this while resetting text to stop undo/redo operation.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.noteBody.setData('',function() { this.resetUndo(); });
```

Have a good day!